# Python mapping Popup out of popup

Tags: python, maps, marker, folium

I'm new here so excuse my poor choice of a title, I'll try my best to explain the issue at hand.
So I made this map using folium in python
the map contains metadata of some places i use as test locations
every place is a popup, when clicked it shows the places name and it's metadata and a hyper link at the end of the metadata that opens a new page that displays a table of content of the specific place, What i'm trying to do here is to make that content display on the same page i don't want to open a new page i want a small window to appear and display the table of contents.
Awaiting your suggestions please.

Comment: Can you add what code you currently have and what about it that you find broken or lacking?

Comment: @Sneaky Polar Bear It's not the code that's broken the code works fine
i want to add a feature and that feature is when i click a hyper link in my marker popup it doesn't open a new window but rather display the content of that window right on top of the marker popup

Comment: I understand, but posting your current code makes it easier for others to understand your current state and issues.